# Oracle filter query not working

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a query as follows-

```
Select t1.colmn1, t2.colm1 from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.pid = t2.pid
and t1.colm2 is null; --- This query retuns 100 rows
```

pid column from table 1 has some null values (say 10 records with pid = null).
I want to modify above query as it should return these null value rows as well.
Like all the 100 records from above query plus 10 records having  `pid = null.`

I tried

```
Select colmn1 from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.pid = t2.pid or t1.pid is null
and t1.colm2 is null;
```

But this query is returning more rows.

I want exact 110 rows. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

**ANSWER**

By using all tricks in following answer. Here is the final query this may help others-

```
Select colmn1
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pid = t2.pid
where (t1.colm2 is null) or (t2.pid is not null)
and t1.colm2 is null
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Your problem could be fixed with parentheses.  But it is better to use proper syntax:

```
Select colmn1
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pid = t2.pid
where t1.pid is null and t1.colm2 is null;
```

I see.  The question is clearer now.  You seem to want a `left join`:

```
Select colmn1
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pid = t2.pid
where (t1.colm2 is null) or (t2.pid is not null);
```

This returns all rows in `table1` that match the `where` conditions, even if they do not match the condition in `table2`.

Comment: This will not give desired result as we are adding t1.pid = null in where condition.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN . . . I see that now.  The edited queries should do what you want.

Comment: The first query in edited answer with left join returns 10 rows only (with null values) and the other one has same result as I was getting.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN . . . My misunderstanding.  I thought you wanted only the `NULL` values.  The `where` clauses are unnecessary.

Comment: `t1.colm2 is null` is required. I just want all rows which matches`t1.pid = t2.pid` condition as well as `t1.pid is null`

Comment: @MicrosoftDN . . . On second though, the version without `join` won't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks.. This worked. the condition (t2.pid is not null) did the trick. Also I added left outer join. Edited the question with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence makes your query like this

```
...or( t1.pid is null and t1.colm2 is null;)
```

Use parentheses or proper JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of Gordon, you need OR condition

```
Select colmn1
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pid = t2.pid
where t1.pid is null
or t1.colm2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`Select colmn1
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.pid = t2.pid(+)
and t1.colm2 is null;`

You can not compare null values on the join, please investigate about  left, right, outer join, previous query indicates that you want all the records that are in both tables plus those one on table2 that has no correspondency with table1.
Also check the next.

`Select colmn1
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.pid(+) = t2.pid
and t1.colm2 is null;`